# Expected Value well-defined

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Say $X$ is an arbitrary random variable

I have been told that $X$ has a well-defined expectation if  $\mathbb E[|X|] < \infty$. Does this mean that if $\mathbb E[X]=\infty$, then $X$ does not have a well-defined expectation? Or can there be cases where $\mathbb E[|X|] < \infty$ while $\mathbb E[X]=\infty$?

I am trying to think of examples on my own, but cannot find one.

In this sense, is the statement: The expectation $\mathbb E[X]$ exists equivalent to the statement $\mathbb E[X]$ is well-defined?

Comment: Note that $-|X| \le X\le |X|$. So if $E[|X|] < \infty$, then we must have $E[X] < \infty$.

Comment: So, if $\mathbb E[X]=\infty$ then the expectation of random variable $X$ does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable which is always nonnegative, then its expectation is always defined, though it may be infinite.

In general, letting $X^+=\max(X,0)$ and $X^-=\max(-X,0)$, so that $X=X^+-X^-$, then both $X^+$ and $X^-$ are always nonnegative, so their expectations are well defined. There are then four cases for $EX$:
$$
\begin{array}{r|cc}
&E[X^+]<\infty & E[X^+]=\infty\\
\hline
E[X^-]<\infty & EX\text{ is finite} & EX=+\infty\\
E[X^-]=\infty & EX=-\infty & EX\text{ is not well defined}
\end{array}
$$ 
Only in the upper left hand corner of that table do we have $E|X|<\infty$.

Whether $EX=\infty$ implies $EX$ exists or not is a matter of convention. Some people say $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}$ does not exist, while others say this limit exists and is equal to $+\infty$. I think most probabalists agree that $\infty$ exists.

In summary, I disagree with the sentiment that $EX$ only exists when $E|X|<\infty$. For example, the St. Petersburg random variable for which $P(X=2^i)=2^{-i}$ for $i\ge 1$ has $E|X|=\infty$, and I would say that $EX$ exists and is equal to $+\infty$.

Comment: Why $E[X^-] = \infty$ and $E[X^+] = \infty$ indicate "$EX$ is not well defined"?

Comment: @namasikanam Because $EX$ would be "$\infty-\infty$" in that case, which has no sensible definition.

Comment: My question actucally comes from a different definition of expected value, which defines $EX$ as infinite summation or Lebesgue integral. I understand, now, this usually a more narrow definition without considering infinity. You are talking about a better definition of $EX$ by considering $E[X^+]$ and $E[X^-]$ at first.